# While updating my product data I got this error "MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving" while updating data in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

Hope you are doing well!
I am working on an e-commerce project. Where I would like to make an API to update the record of the products.
However, while updating it gives me an error which is: "MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving". Although, I do not have _id in my schema but it stills gives error due to the un-presence of _id.
Following is my code of the API and and mongoose schema:

API code:

```
exports.updateProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("UpdateProduct API has been hit.");
  let updatedId = req.params.id;

  //Storage
  const Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "uploads",
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
  });

  //wait

  //upload
  const upload = multer({
    storage: Storage,
  }).single("testImage");

  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      const newImage = new ImageModel({ SKU: updatedId },{$set: {productTitle: req.body.productTitle,
            SKU: updatedId,
            color: req.body.color,
            size: req.body.size,
            price: req.body.price,
            status: req.body.status,
            tag: req.body.status,
            description: req.body.description,
            category: req.body.category,
            subcategory: req.body.subcategory,
            image: {
              data: req.file.filename,
              contentType: "image/png",
            },
          },
        },
        { new: true },
        (err, data) => {
          if (data === null) {
            res.send("No data found. Please fill the forms correctly.");
          } else {
            res.send(data);
          }
        },
        {}
        //{}
      );
      //below write teh save code
      newImage
        .save()
        .then(() =>
          res.send("The product description has been successfully updated..")
        )
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  });

  res.send({ result: "update" });
};
```

Mongoose Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ImageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  productTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  SKU: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  color: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  size: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
  },
  tag: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  subcategory: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  image: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String,
  },
});

module.exports = ImageModel = mongoose.model("imageModel", ImageSchema);
```

Picture of postman API call:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n22co.png)

I tried to send the encrypted id which is linked with the specific product but it also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you provided, it seems like you are trying to create a new document with the same id as existing one. The _id field is unique for each document and you need to provide this when updating. Try this code.

```
// Find the document to update by id and then update
ImageModel.findByIdAndUpdate(updatedId, {
  $set: {
    productTitle: req.body.productTitle,
    SKU: updatedId,
    color: req.body.color,
    size: req.body.size,
    price: req.body.price,
    status: req.body.status,
    tag: req.body.status,
    description: req.body.description,
    category: req.body.category,
    subcategory: req.body.subcategory,
    image: {
      data: req.file.filename,
      contentType: "image/png",
    },
  }
},
  { new: true },
  (err, data) => {
    if (data === null) {
      res.send("No data found. Please fill the forms correctly.");
    } else {
      res.send(data);
    }
  });
```